# Mass editing in <kbd> tags

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits

[Today](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8294036) [I](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8294033) [noticed](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8293994) [a](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8293982) [<2K](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8293725) [user](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8293731) [doing](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8293909) [mass](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8293917) [edits](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8293923) [to](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8293929) [add](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8293965) <kbd>[`<kbd>`](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8293971)</kbd> [tags](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8293980) [to](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8293713) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8293719)[.](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8289525) [This](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8293248) [seems](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8293263) [like](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8293268) [a](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8293271) [lot](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8293341) [of](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8293371) [wasted](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8293415) [effort](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8293421) [for](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8293427) [reviewers](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8293451)[,](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8289564) [but](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8293498) [I](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8293500) [wasn't](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8293508) [positive](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8293521) [there](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8293573) [was](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8293578) [anything](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8293582) [wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8293592) [with](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8293637) [it](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8293642)[.](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8289570)

[Should](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8292402) [anything](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8292509) [be](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8292521) [done](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8292532) [about](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8293168) [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8293225)[?](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8289460)

[Edit:](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8311006) [Now](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8311048) [someone](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8311072) [else](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8312151) [is](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8312161) [doing](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8312225) [it.](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8312230) [I](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8312239) [just](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8312466) [don't](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8312530) [understand](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8312599) [why](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8312604) [they](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8312801) [do](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8312869) [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8312962)

Comment: Yeah, about half the time, the edits are incomplete too.

Comment: Well, that's one way to hit Mortarboard.  Smells like a badge hunter.

Comment: Very lovely link artwork creativity here. +1 , if you find a few more you could even link the ending punctuation marks.

Comment: Soooo tempted to edit each of those links into a `<kbd>` tag...

Comment: I already flagged one of those edits for mod attention as the user seams to be gamifying the system.  They have over 370 rep in the last 4 days from suggested edits.  the flag is still pending at time of writing.

Comment: @NathanOliver: There's absolutely no problem with mass-editing... iff all those edits are really worthwhile. Which they unfortunately aren't in this case.

Comment: @Deduplicator I did not mean to suggest that mass editing is bad.  Mass irrelevant edits are bad.

Comment: +1 Is it just a co-incidence that the number of words in your question matched the number of review links you had or did you play with the words to fit the links in or did you simply left out a few links?

Comment: @akaRash I left out some links.

Comment: +1 for your 60 links... how long did that take?

Comment: @OurManInBananas Given that I'm objecting to this wasting reviewer time, too long :P (about 20 minutes).

Comment: @resueman: quick question, how do I use the <kbd> tag?

Comment: @OurManInBananas double-click the key to add tags to and then Alt+K, I also have a tampermonkey script that adds an extra button for applying / removing the <kbd> tag wrap.

Comment: There's a bunch of bad edits going on... I understand why I stopped reviewing edits.

Comment: By bountying edits with rep we have naturally increased quantity at the cost of quality of edits. I'm not sure that we should be associating rep to <2k users edits at all. I don't think it really wins much, and this bounty isn't even available to >2k users.

Comment: Nice link-only question.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I agree that these are edits that aren't needed. Adding the `<kbd>` tag is pretty unnecessary.  If you run across this and you think that the edits don't offer any sort of improvement, then reject the edit or reject and edit to improve the posts further.

If you think that something else might need to be done aka a moderator needs to be involved here, then find one of the users posts, use a custom "other" flag, explain what is happening and provide some examples. We'll take a look and step in if needed.

Comment: Although these edits are very minor and certainly there could be other improvements made along with some of the edited posts, I disagree with the statement that "[they] don't offer any sort of improvement". In addition to the `<kbd>` tags, there were other formatting improvements in some of the edits, and as you can see from the links in this question, they were mostly approved by reviewers.

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 Many of the edits appear to be adding only the `kbd` but I stated _if you think that they don't offer..., then reject_ I'm not stating to outright reject the edits.

Comment: @rink.attendant.6: mostly, but [this very bad one](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8293521) was *rejected* by only one sharp eyed reviewer and accepted by 3 others. ... Oh the mellifluous irony — **one of them was you**.

Comment: I noticed a lot of these this morning. I started skipping them because it was clear they *would* get approved although in my opinion they actually make it more difficult to read the posts.

Comment: @Jongware I have further edited the question to make additional improvements, but I do not see how that edit in particular caused harm.

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 How did it **make an improvement**? That so many people edited that question and left typos in the title is alarming.

Comment: @TZHX All of the edits in question highlighted *keyboard key combinations* using the `<kbd>` tag which improved formatting and readability, at least in my opinion.

Comment: And in my opinion, they often made it worse or had absolutely no impact.

Comment: I do have a mod flag out there for this on one of the edits that were done.

Comment: I think that it is a recurring theme that maybe its not so much the edits themselves not being an improvement, but more that it's wasting reviewers votes. Users < 2k should be encouraged to make as useful an edit as possible. But for users > 2k mass editing like this where it is more focused on one issue is more acceptable as it doesn't waste anyones votes, as long as it is an improvement. Users > 2k should still strive to make as meaningful an edit as possible.

Answer (score 15):

I can not understand what is the problem with this. The person spends his time doing some edits. Yes, they are not really that amazing, but they still improve the post.

The post becomes nicer to look at when all the key shortcuts are properly formatted. It is similar to hiding links inside of the link tag. Yes, I agree that there are edits that are more useful, but that does not makes his edit bad.

Comment: Do they really improve the post? If that is the objective, then why aren't they improving the *entire* post?

Comment: @Zizouz212 may be because he does not know English good enough to change the grammar. I have seen a lot of edits which are improving grammar, but do nothing to format code and vise versa. Remember that no one pays them, It is like finding a volunteer who paints the house and start accusing that he does a crappy job because he is not removing the trash which is close to the house he is painting.

Comment: But then if they can't make worthwhile edits especially such minor ones, then why are they even going to bother wasting their times and the time of those who review them?

Comment: @Zizouz212 there can be a lot of reasons, starting from they want a badge/few reps, ending to they want to help somehow and this is the only way they can help. All the edits are subjective, so it is in the eye beholder to decide whether to accept or reject it. For example someone might think that changing a minor typo is a good edit, another will find it minor. Someone would think that salvaging crappy useless post is a good edit, another would reject it because there is no point of salvaging nonsense.

Comment: @Zizouz212 Doesn't it increase the load on review edits queue? Isn't that also a significant point?

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar Precisely, it's simply a waste of our time.

Comment: @Zizouz212 some people might argue that edits like this: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8311467are also waste of time. Not really sure how much different removing a word and a tag (which are actually relevant) is from adding hotkey shortcuts. I raised one of your last edits not to shame you, but to show that more than 20% of the edits in a review queue can be viewed as waste of time by someone and helpful by another person.

Comment: Then can you please explain me the difference between visual appeal and removing inappropriate tags?

Comment: If a post has multiple formatting, grammar and spelling issues, I come along and spend 10 minutes improving it trying to fix all of the issues. If in the mean time some robo-editor or a real user comes along and edits just one small issue, then when I try and submit my edit I get a big banner saying the post has been edited. At which point I have to spend even more time finding out exactly what was changed and editing it into my edit if needed so that I don't wipe out the previous improvement, or I abandon it and waste the time. +Now the reviewers have twice the number of edits to review, too.

Comment: Also note difference between 2K+rep user spending own time on edits vs. under-2K-rep user wasting 3x amount

Comment: @Zizouz212 When done right, it's not just visual appeal, it clarifies which keys are pressed together and which in sequence.  That said, it looks like this user wasn't doing that.

Comment: Thanks everyone! Just to add some additional information, the user in question gained close to 400 reputation just to edits. The user has also posted some well communicated answers as well. I understand that there will be differing views, but for someone to come out making seemingly controversial edits for the sake of what seems to be rep is disturbing. Visual appeal, formatting are all good. But note that if that's all that is happening, they're not likely reading the entire post to investigate for other mistakes in grammar, spelling... etc. Include tags, and the title. For someone that...

Comment: is able to post well received answers, we can expect a little more, rather than visual edits. We can't just have someone editing for imaginary internet points. The community will only stay strong by those who put the effort into it, and investigate posts, not adding simple tags, that rarely contribute to the readability of a question or answer.

Comment: You guys ever heard of this guy on Wikipedia: http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2941444/Editor-extraordinaire-Obsessive-software-engineer-corrected-grammar-mistake-astonishing-47-000-times-Wikipedia.html ? I think it can be a good thing.

Comment: @jesterjunk - I've read an article about him; he would disagree and say judgement is actually required to get it right. In his 6000 word essay at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Giraffedata/comprised_of he says 'In any case, the actual editing is an intellectual process. I read the sentence and paragraph, understand what it's supposed to say, and choose a better wording. Sometimes I fix a few other things while I'm in the neighborhood.'

Comment: p.s. He is a Software Engineer. He wrote a program to manage his edits and not wind up re-editing ones that have been rejected by the page author, for example.

Comment: @whybird About 12,200,000 results: http://stackexchange.com/search?q=%22comprised+of%22

Comment: from the [Medium article](https://medium.com/backchannel/meet-the-ultimate-wikignome-10508842caad#.2p4uf0hcy) about him: *Because an individual editor’s allocation of his time shouldn’t be anyone else’s concern.*