# Is it acceptable if a user introduces a new tag that is highly specific?

Tags: discussion, tags

A user is currently mass-editing a new tag into questions: [jacobian-matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jacobian-matrix). [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10937950) is one of the suggested edits (which has already been rejected).

For me this tag seems to be too specific to make sense to attach it to existing questions. If that tag would be acceptable, then it would seem legit to introduce a tag for every specific matrix that has a name, e.g. [unity-matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity-matrix), [rotation-matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rotation-matrix), [cabibbo-kobayashi-maskawa-matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cabibbo-kobayashi-maskawa-matrix), etc.

Is it acceptable if such highly specific tags are created? If not, what can be done in this case?

**Edit:** The question: [Mass editing in <kbd> tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/295858/2675154) proposed as duplicate
might be related, but I think that HTML tags that are edited into posts are
different from tags that are attached to questions. HTML tags are only markup, while the other tags are meant to organize posts on SO.

Comment: IIRC, a custom flag on one of their posts/edits to get a mod's attention is the preferred action.

Comment: @BSMP: Maybe related, but adding HTML tags _into_ posts and attaching tags _to_ questions seems a bit different to me. HTML tags are only markup, while the other tags are meant to organize posts on SO.

Comment: Well, my question is: Is it acceptable if such highly specific are created? That question is not answered in the other question, as far as I can see...

Comment: @honk I also think that tag isn't acceptable. There's not even a reasonable [tag wiki info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jacobian-matrix/info). There are just 17 questions tagged so far, so burinating the tag should be an easy job.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Your suggestion seems sensible to me, but I was not sure whether this is common understanding. Do you mind to put your comment into an answer to see if there are enough users who agree, too?

Comment: The jacobian-matrix tag was added today. It has 16 as of now. LOLCODE tag was added  6 years ago and has a count of 9

Comment: @honk I think I have caught all the tagged questions to remove it right now.

Comment: @Drew: Yes, this is why I was talking about a _new_ tag ;)

Comment: And let's say the gent is a math whiz or the like, and such categorization is germane and useful for those that follow Let's just say. And there were free slots for a tag on a question. They were just blown away.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Ok, I see, such tags are not really wanted. But what do I do if I see something similar coming up again? Hunting down a tag just by myself could become cumbersome. Should I ask another Meta question in such a case?

Comment: @honk Maybe starting the same way as I did and just remove them. I'm at least no expert in tag burination as well :-/ ...

Comment: @Drew: This is why I asked: I was not sure if the tag in question is a doesn't-hurt tag or a bad tag...

Comment: it's not like the tag "data". It is highly selective favor for those that follow to find the stuff.

Comment: The tag data that a gent in our socvr room single-handedly took on to cleanse out of 8000 questions

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Well, if one user adds new tags and another removes them, then the story could go on for quite some while...

Comment: @Drew: I know that some users seem to be present on SO 24/7, but unfortunately I cannot spend as much time on SO as I would like to...

Comment: I am not suggesting that anyone do that. In the data case, I believe that could be across the board blown away by The Borg and not rest on a person or a group. But if someone takes the time to make stuff easier to find for others, then what was just done doesn't seem to make sense. We have like 40 to 60 k  tags. Some have 0 or 1 in them

Comment: @Drew: You are hitting the right point: Tags only make sense if the number of tags is much lower than the number of questions. Otherwise you could also do a full-text search. So, how many tags make sense? Assume that you have 1000 xxx-matrix tags. If you then enter 'matrix' into the tag line, then you might need to wade through pages to find the correct tag. Of course I'm overstating the problem here, but the question is: How specific should tags be so that they still make sense?

Comment: Perhaps he is writing his doctorial thesis on a jabocian-matrix. Perhaps he could be invited into a chat room like we always do and chat about his intentions. Perhaps the tags that have absolutely no value could be targeted prior to un-doing hard work

Comment: @Drew: I came to chat in the first place, directly after spotting those edits. The first suggestion after some time was: _"I would start a meta discussion..."_ This is why I asked here...

Comment: @honk _"I know that some users seem to be present on SO 24/7"_ Besides for the community user, that's a plain myth ;-) ...

Comment: Has anyone pinged the editor about this discussion?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: I don't know. For example, you also seem to be always on when I am ;)

Comment: @honk What's your timezone? I usually sleep 4-7 hrs nightly :-) ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: UTC+1. And I try to sleep 7 hrs per night. Too long?

Comment: @AndrasDeak: I didn't.

Comment: I've pinged the editor on it.  I've also removed those tags as well as did some light editing on questions that needed it.  It may also be worth considering what the cut-off for questions with a mathematical function should be, per [this discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/314979/1079354).

Comment: @honk _"And I try to sleep 7 hrs per night. Too long?"_ Certainly not too long, it's just erm **I'm** getting old (not to say senile) now :-P ...

Comment: @AndrasDeak Apparently not, he's still tagging questions.

Comment: @Makoto: Thank you. I think your answer on the other question would also have been fine here. More or less...

Comment: I think there's a separate issue at hand here:  whether or not the math tags are considered meta tags.  This question is more general in that it's asking if it's okay to introduce a very specific tag.

Comment: Hi everyone. I'm so disappointed at Stackoverflow moderation. Thanks to @Makoto for letting me know what's going on here. All I wanted to do was helping people and stackoverflow users!
My work contains a lot of mathematical optimization stuff. I know that  those tags are very important for people like me.

Comment: I spent a lottttttt of time on finding questions having something to do with Jacobian matrix and now it's all ruined. Why did you guys do this?

Comment: Jacobian matrix is a very important thing in mathematics. A lot of mathematical optimization algorithms use Jacobian matrices and a lot of the questions that I edited need to be tagged with Jacobian matrix. This way people who look up something related to Jacobian matrix on search engines will be able to find the material easier as well.

Comment: @Amir no offense, but you should use google or the SO search engine for finding what interests you. Creating tags for things that are irrelevant to the vast majority of programmers here is not helpful. Otherwise I completely agree that you should've been informed about this procedure at the very beginning.

Comment: There are millions of things related to a tag like `Jacobian-matrix`. But why the tag is unnecessary and a tag like pycaffe is?!! `pycaffe` is exactly equivalent to `caffe` with the difference that it is Python-based

Comment: @Amir If you think that the tag should be allowed, post an answer with your reasoning and let everyone consider it. Complaining in the comments is not the way to go about this.

Comment: @AndrasDeak You're kind of right, but well people like me are also programmers. But we are programmers who continuously work with stuff like Hessian matrix, Jacobian matrix and a lot of similar things. We also have programming questions regarding these stuff and the questions that I tagged were almost always related to programming.

Comment: @Amir: I'm sorry, my intention was not to disappoint you. If you edits would have been acceptable, then there would have been no need to bother you with my question. Please also read [this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/314979/2675154), because it is also related to your edits and has an answer.

Comment: I just wanted to have my own contribution to the SO community

Comment: @Amir don't be disappointed, your contributions are always welcome. It just has to be sorted out whether the Community agrees with you (in this case, probably not). But I advise you to heed [@beaker's suggestion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314976/is-it-acceptable-if-a-user-introduces-a-new-tag-that-is-highly-specific#comment295876_314976) and explain your intentions. You can get valuable feedback on that. I know it doesn't help at all that you've just found yourself in the middle of this counter-action to your tagging, and you feel violated despite your best intentions.

Comment: @honk I know that your intention is to help the community. But Jacobian matrix is not something that should be ignored this way and it's not a specific `function`. It's something used world-wide extensively by almost any industry and engineering-related matter that has something to do with calculus. If `jacobian matrix` does not deserve to be on Stackoverflow, please look at the tag `levenberg-marquardt`. Why should this tag exists? `levenberg-marquardt' is an extremely narrowed-down subject in optimization and mathematics. I think someone should come up with a more reasonable answer.

Comment: Amir, write that in an *Answer* below

Comment: @Amir that is a different question altogether. Because some crap tags are around, doesn't mean you can/should create one. You should bring up this notion in an answer, `levenberg-marquardt` and friends could as easily be removed, if it's decided. Also, [here's a blog post of why meta-tags are considered bad](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/), your mileage may vary about whether these are meta-tags.

Comment: @Amir *“Jacobian matrix is a very important thing in mathematics”* – And I think that’s the problem. It’s more a [mathematical](http://math.stackexchange.com/) or [theoretical computer science](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/) thing than something closely related to programming (and as such SO).

Comment: @poke If that is the case, why there are quite a lot of questions having the term `jacobian` in their title on Stackoverflow? They all have something to do with programming as well :)
People who get on Stackoverflow to ask something about `jacobians` are different from people on math.stackexchange.com. The later are more looking for mathematical proofs and details of mathematical algorithms rather than programming stuff.

Comment: @Amir I’m just saying that just because you can apply an algorithm, a method or a technique with programming, that doesn’t mean that it’s exactly a programming topic, and even less likely requires its own tags. With currently 212 questions, it doesn’t seem such a big topic on SO and is often paired with tags like `matrix` or `algorithm` or `matlab`. I think that covers the link well enough: It’s just an application of maths. And for the actual maths, you can go to math.SE (which actually has over 1000 questions about jacobian matrices—a tag there would make more sense).

Comment: There is also the hessian-matrix tag that is also used "a lot"... currently 65 questions

Comment: I don't see how the jacobian-matrix tag is irrelevant. What concerns me is tag limits. Most of the time, I have to cut down the amount of tags that I want to add. If Amir was simply *adding* the tag, I don't see the issue. If he was removing existing tags to make room due to the tag limit, well that's a big fat problem.

Answer (score -7, accepted):

This is a [meta tag](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) and does not belong on SO.  Quoting from that post there are two ways to see if something is a meta tag:

1. If the tag can't work as the only tag on a question, it's probably a
   meta-tag.
2. If the tag commonly means different things to different people, it's
   probably a meta-tag

And I believe it fails test #1.  If it is the only tag, then it isn't very useful.  If it is paired with, say Java, then you can attract the right people who can help.  They can help you debug your implementation or whatever.  Without it, all you can see with that information is that it is a math problem.  Which probably belongs on Math.SE, not SO.

Just because you can apply something from some other field doesn't automatically make it a good candidate for a tag.  Should every art style have a tag because someone wants to replicate it in their own art program?  Should every engineering or science principle have a tag because simulators exist?  Do we need a pythagorian-theorum tag?  Should ASCII-art and Trogdor tags be a thing?  (If so, I have plans...)

To more directly address the question about what to do, first see if it passes or fails the meta tag test.  Unless you are 100% certain of your findings there, check with Meta or raise a mod flag.

Comment: If this is the case (I'm not arguing either way), a huge bunch of low-traffic math tags should also be burninated. Like `sieve`, `sieve-of-eratosthenes`, and the like (I'm sure there are a lot of others).

Comment: @AndrasDeak probably.  Whether those low-traffic tags are worth the effort to burninate is separate consideration.

Comment: @AndrasDeak But there you're talking about specific algorithms.

Comment: @beaker I also tend to agree that a specific algorithm conveys a bit more information. But there's still a bit of subjectivity to #1 of the meta-tag-test questionnare, at least in this respect (and probably others as well). I'm just saying that I understand why Amir is confused/taken aback.

Comment: While I agree that `jacobian-matrix` isn't appropriate, labeling it a meta-tag completely misses the point.  A meta-tag is an attempt to label the question itself, giving potential searchers no indication what it's about.  This one is just off-topic.

Comment: These "tests" are for correlation, and require closer inspection.  They do not in any way define what meta tags are.  `jacobian-matrix` is not a meta-tag.

Comment: "it is a math problem. Which probably belongs on Math.SE, not SO." just like all the [tag:graph-theory] and [tag:combinatorics] problems I see are just math problems, I suppose. Writing a program to take a derivative or construct a Jacobian is not some esoteric task, even if they don't yet teach it in the standard CS curriculum ... Would you also burninate the [tag:mathematical-optimization] tag?

Comment: Whow. Great discussion here! And even though it is highly controversial, I still have the feeling that we don't really need the tag in question. Nevertheless, it was hard to nominate the most helpful answer. But the green check mark thighy goes to you, because you addressed my question most directly. Anyway, thank you to all who provided answers and comments.

Comment: This tag is nothing like the "meta tags" described in that post. Not even close. There might be reasons not to support it as a tag, but that's a poor one.

Comment: Point 1 is not a definitive test for a meta tag the clue is in the quote "it's probably a meta tag" - if it fails that then it could be a meta tag or it could be off topic. if there are no other on-topic tags then it could be an indicator that this should be moved and actually specific tags like this could be helpful for moderators when deciding if a question is on or off topic

Answer (score 59):

I'm going to take a contrarian view here:

[jacobian-matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jacobian-matrix) is a valid tag. It's not ambiguous (everyone who sees it thinks of exactly the same definition), and it's at least somewhat possible for people to be expert in calculating and manipulating Jacobian matrices (there is a world of numeric accuracy concerns around calculation of derivatives) and therefore want to put such a tag on their favorites list... or be bored to death by beginning MATLAB students asking the same Jacobian matrix problem over and over and want to ignore it.

At the same time, it isn't a mega-important classification. We don't need a way to find all questions somewhat linked to Jacobians. If the question asker didn't feel that [jacobian-matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jacobian-matrix) was the core issue he was struggling with, or something that defines the group of experts who could help answer, then it isn't useful to add that tag to that question.

Therefore, please:

1. No mass-addition of [jacobian-matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jacobian-matrix) or [hessian-matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hessian-matrix) or [levenberg-marquardt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/levenberg-marquardt).
2. No burnination of these perfectly valid tags either.

Of course, the guidance on suggested edits remains:

3. When you edit-bump a post, do your best to fix as many issues as possible.

This by itself rules out mass sprees of identical edits... because the other corrections needed will vary significantly between posts.

Comment: The problem with accepting jacobian-matrix as a tag is, that there are thousands of mathematical/numerical methods, matrices, etc that are then allowed to have their own tag!

Comment: @ander that is correct and it is not a problem

Comment: Your second paragraph refers to a mistaken premise, I think; the tag didn't exist before Amir started adding it, so possibly *all* previous askers of Jacobian-related questions probably weren't able to add it to begin with. The point being that we can't reliably say previous question askers didn't feel the tag was appropriate, because it simply wasn't an option. Even if they had the requisite reputation, they might not be familiar with the method of adding a new tag. I agree with your conclusions, though.

Comment: @tylerh 1 rep is enough to leave a request, either as comment or in the question, for a higher user to edit it in.

Comment: @BenVoigt Do you think the average 1-rep user know what it takes to create a tag?

Comment: @TylerH: Yes, considering it's shown in a red popup when they try and fail.  Also, are you supposing that not a single one of the edits was suggested to a question where the posted did have enough reputation?

Comment: @TylerH: FWIW, look at revision 4 here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/1695/revisions

Comment: @BenVoigt I supposed it as a possible scenario, but wasn't suggesting it as reality. Also, most users probably wouldn't know to try to create the tag. From my experience, that kind of contributory behavior is common for more inquisitive power-user types, not the kind of person who usually asks questions here (as we know from the general quality of questions being asked)

Comment: @TylerH you can't create tag until 1500 rep on SO.

Comment: @Braiam Yes, that's partially my point.

Comment: As much as I hate a strawman argument... "Homework is a valid tag.  It's not ambiguous (everyone who sees it thinks of exactly the same definition), and it's at least somewhat possible for people to be expert in solving homework problems."  [Maybe, just maybe, they're meta tags.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/314984/1079354)

Comment: @Makoto: Nope, "homework" doesn't mean the same thing to everyone.  It truly is a meta tag.  [tag:jacobian-matrix] is not a meta-tag.  I didn't explain why it's not a meta-tag, because it follows directly from the meaning of "meta".  The only people having trouble are the ones applying some arbitrary rule intended to aid in the identification of meta tags, not to define them, in lieu of knowing what "meta" means.

Comment: Fair enough.  Let's take it in another direction, then:  would a question asking about Jacobian matrices make sense on Stack Overflow, and if so, under what guise?  In the answer I linked to prior, I discussed that there is the possibility of these questions being available in math software like R, MATLAB, or Mathematica.  It's also possible that someone could ask about this matrix as if they're attempting to implement it.  At that point, what value of this particular tag (or any Math-related tag) actually add?

Comment: @Makoto: That information has been in my answer since the beginning, and I just wrote one on the other question as well.

Comment: I think that the main point I'm taking umbrage with here is that you still believe these tags to be "perfectly valid".  No question here tagged *exclusively* with that is going to be valid here; at *best*, it'll be closed as off-topic and askers would get redirected to Math.SE.

Comment: @Makoto: There's not a tag on this site that couldn't be applied to an off-topic question.  "Can't be used exclusively" is not a defining characteristic of a meta tag, or even a bad tag.  It's just correlated.  And I don't think I even believe that "can't be used exclusively" is even true.  Good questions are surely possible that are tagged only "floating-point" and "jacobian matrix", and neither of those tags is software-specific, so how is one "good" and the other "bad".

Comment: If you can find a question that is tagged similarly with jacobian-matrix (or any other math-related function) and another, language-agnostic tag that *isn't* filled with a deluge of software engineers sounding puzzled or asking for clarification, then I'll reconsider my stance.

Comment: @Makoto: A majority of software engineers being bad at math does not mean that math software is not interesting.  A majority of software engineers are bad at functional programming too,  You brought up the straw man, so try "If you can find a question tagged [tag:monads] that isn't filled with a deluge of software engineers sounding puzzled"...  Some concepts are not easy.  That makes them *more* valuable for tagging, not less.

Comment: @Makoto Would a question with only [tag:aggregate] be valid? I would say "no," but would not then go on to say the tag should not exist. I'm not saying Jacobians merit a tag, just that you need to give a better reason for why they don't. (I follow [tag:aggregate] and [tag:graph-theory] and think they're quite harmless.) Is there a link for this deluge of confused software-engineer questions you mention? I don't think I really follow where you're going with that.

Comment: @BenVoigt:  To your point, monads are well-defined in the scope of software engineering, specifically functional programming.  They have roots in math as well, but there are classes of languages (Scala, Haskel, J, etc) that actually make use of this concept.

Comment: @Makoto: Absolutely [tag:monads] is a valid concept for tagging.  I'm just using it to make the point that being well-understood by most programmers is not a prerequisite for a good tag.

Comment: @Frank:  Aggregate has its place in software engineering, but its usage is muddled.  You can get the aggregate as part of a function in several languages, and you can do so with the `SUM` function in SQL, too.  Graph theory questions get interesting since, while those are valid software engineering problems, the "theory" part makes it sound more like a comp-sci problem.  But I don't disagree with your logic, there.

Comment: @BenVoigt:  Again, I defend monads as a concept and a tag because there are classes of actual software engineering problems dedicated to them.  Given its usage, I believed that jacobian-matrix *wasn't*, since it doesn't describe an actual software engineering problem.  We could go back and forth on this, but I think now's a good place to agree to disagree.

Answer (score 15):

Adding a very specific tag would only be valuable if the very specific tag could also fulfill its concrete duties as a tag.

That is, I'd be okay with a specific tag if and *only if*:

- It supported a class of on-topic questions for Stack Overflow,
- It described a specific and exact subject or problem, and
- It did not require any other tags to support itself to avoid the [meta tag problem](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/)

With that said, [jacobian-matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jacobian-matrix) fails two out of three.

- Questions that are just about the Jacobian matrix have [a better home on Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=jacobian) than here, since they're not about a specific software engineering problem.
- If you're asking about the Jacobian matrix, invariably you need to include information about your approach. However, this is not crystal clear; you may either be using Mathematica, MATLAB, R, or hand-writing your solution.

  In the former two cases, just use the software that you're using and describe what problem it is you're having with it.  In the latter case, it certainly *describes* what you're trying to solve, but just because you're writing a Jacobian matrix in JavaScript doesn't mean that anyone that knows what a Jacobian matrix is would be of any help to you.

Comment: "...writing a Jacobian matrix in JavaScript doesn't mean that anyone that knows what a Jacobian matrix is would be of any help to you" Why not? It certainly helps to know what a Jacobian matrix is in order to write a Jacobian matrix in any language.

Comment: @Trilarion that doesn't mean that they will know **how to answer** your question. Remember, tags are to target potential answerers.

Comment: @Braiam You mean anyone can implement a Jacobian matrix in JavaScript even if he has no knowledge about Jacobian matrices? To me tags are just classifications, I don't require strictly that every tag can completely stand on its own.

Comment: @Trilarion If he knows how to represent matrices and calculate partial derivatives, yes. You don't even need to know what a Jacobian matrix is, in fact, I know how to make them after reading WP article and I've never seen one in my life.

Comment: @Braiam The Jacobian is just the matrix of all partial derivatives (Jij=dfi/dxj as it says in Wikipedia). This is indeed not a big business. It just happens that it has a special name and some people will recognize it more easily. I have seen some in my life and I guess now that you are mostly right. The tag doesn't add much and would be used only rarely. We don't need it.

Comment: Those are three very arbitrary requirements. Do most tags meet them? Does [leaflet] "describe a specific and exact problem"?

Comment: @SteveBennett: Let's be fair here: picking a random tag and trying to use it to shore up a tag in dispute isn't all that likely to work well, because, if it's sufficiently similar to be interesting in a debate, chances are pretty good it's *also* a candidate for burnination. SO has a *lot* of bad tags. Not as high a proportion as ELL, but still a lot.

Comment: Ok, so address my main point: the three criteria proposed here are totally arbitrary. Why should we care whether a given tag meets them?

Comment: @SteveBennett:  At the bare minimum, if the tag is about something off-topic for a site, then where those types of questions should exist should be brought up.   Further, these requirements were derived from existing, good tags here.  If we have tags that are irrelevant and useless, then they're cluttering up the site and preventing others from getting their questions in front of experts.

Comment: @Trilarion i read the javascript comment as meaning that someone could help solve a javascript specific problem (that so happened to involve a jacobian matrix) without knowing what a jacobian matrix is and vice versa, therefore making the tag confusing and potentially useless

Answer (score 4):

I know that your intention is to help the community, but the Jacobian matrix is not something that should be ignored this way and it's not a specific function. It's something used worldwide extensively by almost any industry and engineering-related matter that has something to do with calculus. If [jacobian-matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jacobian-matrix) does not deserve to be on Stack Overflow, please look at the tag [levenberg-marquardt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/levenberg-marquardt). Why should this tag exist? [levenberg-marquardt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/levenberg-marquardt) is an extremely narrowed-down subject in optimization and mathematics. I think someone should come up with a more reasonable answer.

I think the only reason this discussion was created is because I created the tag and decided to reorganize the questions related to [jacobian-matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jacobian-matrix). This created a wave of interest on what I'm doing.

Comment: Note that [`levenberg-marquardt`](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/levenberg-marquardt/info) has only 46 questions and no tag wiki, with a very short excerpt. It is easily eligible for burnination, just like your tag. Also, there are many opinions, and only discussion will lead to a mutually satisfactory solution. This is why we're pushing you to express your opinion and concerns in an answer. Enumerating your reasons for why this tag should exist can make others provide their own pros and cons.

Comment: No doubt, there are many "sub-optimal" tags on SO. But that shouldn't be a reason to add more of them (sorry to say so). Every matrix that has a name seems to be quite important. If we would add a tag for all of them, then we would end up with hundreds of matrix tags, I guess...

Comment: It's also worth pointing out that this was only caught by the three users who initially noticed it (Honk, Mogsdad, and myself) because you're not yet at 2,000 reputation, so your edits are placed in the review queue. Had you been above 2,000 reputation, it's likely that we wouldn't have been made aware. In this case I think the system is working as intended; to catch systemic edits that are contentious.

Comment: But the thing is some detailed-oriented people like me need to use such tags. When I look up something related to `levenberg-marquardt` method I would like to easily click on the tag and read more about the topic. I definitely think `jacobian-matrix` must be there. It's not even comparable to `levenberg-marquardt`. It is used in any calculus-related thing in the world! It is extensively used in many important subjects and I believe it has the right to be there.

Comment: @TylerH also note that the front page had quite a few questions in this tag, which could've drawn attention anyway (but of course a review queue makes people more careful and critical).

Comment: @Amir I don't think anyone's saying that Jacobians are unimportant, but rather that a tag on SO is uncalled for. Why can't you search for ["Jacobian"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jacobian+is%3Aquestion) in questions/answers? Why won't that be useful? Also: areas like [image-processing] are different in the sense that questions probably don't have "image-processing" in them. However, you can only talk about Jacobians by saying "Jacobian". This is a minor technical detail, but it implies that searching for this term should be a worst-case substitute if your tag remains dead.

Comment: @Amir At least you should have created a reasonable tag-info description that clearly describes how jacobian-matrix differs from the usual matrices, including some common references that people can learn from. Just providing a new tag isn't really helpful.

Comment: It seems like the interesting question is whether someone would say "I want to follow/answer questions about Jacobian matrices."

Comment: There are almost 600 Jacobians on the stack. About 150 with matlab. I am in full favor of jacobian-matrix. It is time for it to have a home. Easily found. In the same way I appreciated the easy ways to *find* (not *follow*) Diffie-Hellman and bouncycastle

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I did! It's been rejected two times and I gave up on it!!!

Comment: My edit reputation has gone down so bad today. I had only less than 80 rejects and more than 4xx approved edits. Now I have about 140 rejects ... So disappointed

Comment: @Amir _"I did! It's been rejected two times ..."_ So you might need to have more rep doing such things to really get through. Sorry.

Comment: The more I read your rationale, the more this tag sounds like a [meta tag](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/).  This is why I've been removing them; a question simply tagged with jacobian-matrix can't survive on Stack Overflow by itself.  It's at *best* off-topic and at *worst* deeply flawed.

Comment: @Amir "`It's been rejected two times and I gave up on it!!!`", I suggest bringing such issues to meta, that's most helpful to everyone involved.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Well this is the first time I know about Meta. I created my account here today.

Comment: @Amir If your suggested edits are getting rejected, there's a reason.

Comment: @Makoto but at the same time Amir is right that a bunch of other math-related meta-tags are around. Those should be cleaned up as well (in a very ideal world, after a lot of meta-discussion).

Comment: @AndrasDeak:  Yes, but again, it doesn't mean that it's okay to add more because they already exist.  Cleanup *must* start happening.

Comment: @Makoto [I fully agree](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314976/is-it-acceptable-if-a-user-introduces-a-new-tag-that-is-highly-specific#comment295885_314976)

Comment: @Drew And 46,000 [tag:matrix] questions. Jacobian is a tiny fraction.

Comment: @beaker So please reason why this description for the tag should be rejected? `Jacobian matrix is an M x N matrix containing the first-order partial derivatives of a vector-valued function of size M with respect to its N variables. If the function outputs a single value, the Jacobian is equivalent to the gradient vector.`

Comment: I have no doubts about your good intention, I have no idea about the tags, my only advice is to be careful on SO (better safe then sorry) before taking massive decisions.... Keep up your moral I appreciate your love for jacobian-matrix..

Comment: @Amir I didn't reject it. I'm not going to speak for anybody else. I'm not even going to look at the suggested edit to see if I agree or disagree. If you disagree with the rejection, post a question here on meta, present your case, and discuss it.

Comment: Back in the day when I was writing crypto, fortunately certain math/crypto tags were allowed to exist (and still do) even if people on meta never used them

Comment: @Amir: "*I had only less than 80 rejects and more than 4xx approved edits. Now I have about 140 rejects ... So disappointed*" Let that be a lesson to you then: stop spree-editing. Edit a few at a time, not dozens in one day.

Comment: Well the reason that I have edited a lot of questions is that I had a sense of helping the community. I understand why many questions have incorrect tags or are missing the tags they should have been tagged with. This is because most people on Stackvoerflow only do programming and have nothing to do with math almost. I'm not a mathematician myself and I'm just taking some baby steps, but I felt I need to do some reorganizations for people like me who. I did not know this is going to happen ...

Comment: On the topic of `levenberg-marquardt`, [`Newton's Method`](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/newtons-method/info) also has a tag - and that's just a single example of a specific use of a Jacobian matrix.

Comment: @J... one could argue that Newton's Method is a specific algorithm, and holds specific information related to programming (unlike "Jacobian matrix"). This either can or cannot justify its being a tag on its own. Following this logic there are tags like [`sieve-of-eratosthenes`](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/sieve-of-eratosthenes/info) or just [`sieve`](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/sieve/info) which should or should not be burninated in the same wave.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Indeed - I think I tend to agree.  After all, most Newton's Method questions don't actually have anything to do with Jacobians - there is, one would say, more *meat* to an entire algorithm than simply to a basic ingredient (type of matrix).

Comment: I think the worst part is that none of the post's content is actually being fixed in the process.  You're just adding the tag!  That may be what I'm taking the most umbrage to here.

Comment: [Yesterday's spree](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2838606/amir?tab=reputation) was [tag:hessian-matrix], today it's [tag:jacobian-matrix]

Comment: The tag [tag:hessian] was too ambiguous. There is server/client program named hessian and there is an mathematical concept name "hessian-matrix". All hessian matrix related questions were tagged with [tag:hessian]

Comment: @Amir, I'm just guessing here: don't you think that creating a tag for "Hessian matrix" and then going on an edit spree will have the same kind of impact as creating a tag for "Jacobian matrix" and then going on an edit spree? Or did you do `hessian-matrix` first? Anyway, you're right that those were mistagged. What I'm saying is that the sure course of action is *to remove the wrong tags*, not to create a new tag. Rule of thumb: don't create a new tag. (If `hessian` was first to you, then I guess you've figured this out by yourself now).

Comment: @Amir: 80 rejections and 4xx accepted is a *terrible* ratio.  People who are doing it right have acceptance rate well above 95%.

Comment: No I had created the tag before.

Answer (score 2):

The term "Jacobian matrix" just denotes a mathematical concept like many others. Computer science and programming uses a lot of mathematics. The tag surely has the potential to attract a few tens or even a couple of hundred questions on StackOverflow. In this regard it is maybe similar to a quite obscure file format.

While it cannot stand on its own so well (because StackOverflow is not a pure math site) it can describe a subclass of problems rather well, that is the subclass of "implementating and/or using the Jacobian matrix efficiently in a specific language".

So I don't see that it has to go but also I don't see that it has to stay (because of low expected interest anyway). It's a border case.