# When do we need to create a tag for a math function?

Tags: discussion, tags

Someone decided to create a tag for calculating Jacobian matrices and determinants, basically a tag for a function, but if I'm reading [Wikipedia correctly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant) I could roll my own. Well, there are some libraries that allows you to calculate the said matrix if you just pass the values. Said libraries (in some cases like Mathematica, the language itself provides the function) already have tags on their own. Do we need to create the tags nonetheless?

This is a question specific about mathematic functions. There are already some tags about math functions, but I want to know where is the cutoff.

Comment: Can I suggest your question as duplicate of my question? ;)

Comment: @honk no........ >:/

Comment: I didn't do it. Was just kidding...

Comment: Related discussion of the jacobian matrix tag and the user who created it: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314976/is-it-acceptable-if-a-user-introduces-a-new-tag-that-is-highly-specific

Comment: Why not? [tag:cos] we already have [tag:sin].

Comment: Does "When we are on Math.se." or "Never" constitute an answer to the question?

Comment: @JoshuaDrake Yes, though not necessarily a good one.

Answer (score 13):

I was noticing this too, while looking into the jacobian-matrix tag earlier.  It seems to me that the cut-off for these questions and tagging them as such falls into two categories.

- If the question is asking about a specific piece of software or library that *provides* that function, then the question should be simply tagged *with the library or software*.  Adding the other tags doesn't improve its target audience, nor does that tag make the question more on-topic.
- If the question is looking to attempt an implementation of the mathematical operation in code *without* the use of libraries or other software, then I suppose that's more of a case-by-case thing that we'd need to suss out.  Personally, I see these tags as meta tags.

  As an example, there are questions tagged with [derivative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/derivative) and [integral](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/integral), but they don't describe the actual problem on their own.  Depending on the context, they may even be off-topic; I'd have to peruse them to see if they'd be worth asking on/migrating to Math.SE.

It won't be an easy answer for the latter, but the former is straightforward.  If they're looking at R, Matlab or Mathematica and want to get a mathematical operation but they're having trouble with it, then tagging it with one of those three is enough.

Comment: Who would follow a jacobian-matrix tag? Are there jacobian-matrix experts trying to easily find jacobian-matrix questions?

Comment: @DavidConrad: If there are, I would expect them to dwell more on Math.SE than here.

Comment: Nope, they aren't meta tags.  They very much describe the algorithm being implemented, rather than programmer writing the algorithm.

Comment: @BenVoigt:  I've yet to peruse the questions tagged either derivative or integral, but I will agree that those sorts of tags need to be taken on a case-by-case basis.  I'm not interested in saying in blanket that this definitely *isn't* a meta tag since their usage has been just that.

Answer (score -4):

Your lack of understanding of the right way to build a Jacobian matrix (hint: calling some magic function to do it is the worst option) shows why it actually is an area of expertise, which makes it ripe for tagging.

(I'm not a guru-level expert, but I do know that it is far better to do the derivative analytically, then plug in the coordinates, than numeric evaluation of the partial derivatives.  And if you do use numerical evaluation, perhaps because no analytic form of the function is known, then there are a lot of accuracy concerns which can quickly lead to stability problems in use of the Jacobian -- the accuracy details may be common to floating-point, but the stability concerns, which will guide the tradeoffs you make in calculation, are more specific.)

Comment: Your lack of understanding that this is a general question for **all mathematical functions** shows why this is not your area of expertise. One of the most valued characteristics of any programming context is consistency. If we want consistency then either we establish the bases of this consistencies or we cry.

Comment: @Braiam: You err in thinking that there is a general answer that can be given for all math stuff.  And that "Jacobian matrix" is a function in the first place.

Comment: @Braiam: But your question asked when a tag is needed, and my answer does say that -- when it is an area of expertise.  How a non-expert can recognize that is a prickly problem of course, it's common for non-experts to fail to recognize the difficulty of a given mathematical area to begin with.

Comment: I really don't care that jacobian matrix are a function or not, what I do care is that we are programmers in a site about programming **first and foremost**. Having a tag for, i. e. second order condition or Hessian matrices (both math concepts applied to economy), doesn't mean that I will go to SO to get help solving my economy problems. Nor I would follow those tags.

Comment: @Braiam: Economics are merely one application area for optimization, which is where these ideas really live.  And there are a TON of software/programming topics surrounding implementation of optimization algorithms, which are particular to optimization (but completely independent of the vertical market, i.e. economics).