# From the sum of tags, remove the redundancy that is [subtract] and [subtraction]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

Alias [subtract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/subtract) and [subtraction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/subtraction).

I think this is very self-explanatory.

I can't take away¹ the feeling that either one of these tags should go, but since I don't have a score of 5 in this tag, I can't suggest aliases myself.

---

¹sorry, the puns just don't get any better; anyway, they would subtract your attention from the obvious redundancy.

Comment: Both tag wiki excerpts are also redundant with Wikipedia.

Comment: I say, burninate both. And add [tag:addition], [tag:multiplication] and [tag:division] in the fire as well...

Comment: @Tunaki: I'd agree that this isn't the most high quality tag, but burninating a >280 q tag sounds a bit extreme

Comment: Synonymize them all with [tag:math]

Comment: @TinyGiant: no. [tag:math] is sooo much more than basic arithmetics and even more importantly, math doesn't care about why your specific CPU doesn't do what you think it should if you subtract a float from another float etc. That would be a total mis-synonym.

Comment: Math is about any mathematical operation. None of the referenced tags here care about why your specific CPU doesn't do what you think it should. There is also [tag:floating-point] for what you're talking about, and notice that the canonical [tag:language-agnostic] [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/588004) is not tagged with any of the specific mathematical operation tags, it is however tagged with [tag:math], [tag:floating-point], and [tag:floating-accuracy]. Your point is moot. These tags are unnecessary, the only necessary tag is the [tag:math] tag.

Comment: @TinyGiant: ok, good point. But still, if we create a synonym [tag:subtraction] with [tag:math], we can also do the same for [tag:ruby-on-rails] and e.g. [tag:web-development] (don't know whether these exist)...

Comment: That's... a bit of a stretch. If you follow that train, you could synonymize every tag on the site to [tag:programming]. The point is that differentiating between addition and subtraction in the tags does not add anything to the question. It's still just math. Tags should help classify questions, there's nothing special about subtraction as opposed to addition.

Comment: My reaction to this comment chain: https://xkcd.com/435/

Comment: @TinyGiant exactly my point. In English and in general, *math* and *subtraction* are **not** even remotely synonyms. You can subtract without being very mathematically conscious about it (as you can do web development without being overly conscious of the electrical signals that run your server), and you can do math without subtracting (much like you can have digital logic but not build a ruby on rails application).

Comment: subtraction, addition, multiplication, and division are all unnecessary disambiguations of math. The biggest problem that I see is that a great number of the questions tagged with any of those unnecessary sub-tags are not actually tagged with math, which would actually help classify the questions. No one is going to be an expert in just subtraction, but there are a multitude of math experts on this site.

Comment: @TinyGiant *unnecessary disambiguations of math*: no, I politely disagree. They would be an unnecessary disambiguation of [tag:basic-arithmetic] or so, but not of math. Math problems can be much more diverse than just centering around a single elementary operation, and melding those tags into math does neither of them any good.

Comment: Subtraction is math, just because math *can* be more complicated, doesn't mean that the math tag can only be applied to questions about complicated mathematical operations. The tag isn't named advanced-math, it is named math. Also, basic-arithmetic is not a tag... because it is just math.

Comment: @TinyGiant there's a lot of *-arithmetic tags. Really, [tag:math] is just too universal. It doesn't fit enough of the actual [tag:subtraction] questions.

Comment: subtraction is math, how can a subtraction question not also be a math question?

Comment: it is, but as you said, all SO questions are by definition programming questions, too.

Comment: This discussion isn't going anywhere.

Comment: @TinyGiant o, rly? :) Point is, you still agree [tag:subtract] and [tag:subtraction] are identical. So let's get *this* synonym done with, and then let's open a new meta Q discussing synonyming [tag:subtraction] and [tag:math], separately.

Comment: For the sake of argument alone, I'll take your tactic and say that no: subtract and subtraction are not identical. Subtraction is too universal. It doesn't fit enough of the actual subtract questions.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/314979/792066

Comment: Related http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316467/whats-the-point-of-generic-math-operation-tags

Comment: I propose that the correct larger category for these would be [tag:arithmetic-operators].  That automatically excludes fancy math functions such as bessel, etc.  And it includes the bits of [tag:subtraction] or [tag:addition] that aren't actually math or arithmetic related, for example operator overloading and operand type coercion.