# I want a university specific tag called 'Avans'

Tags: feature-request, tags

I am a teacher at Avans University for applied science. For a programming course in C# I want to give students the possibility to ask questions via Stackoverflow. This is a way for me to introduce them to the platform and make the students more active members of the community. 
I want to recognize all the questions asked via Stackoverflow and I would like a custom university tag to recognize these questions. I don't have enough Stackoverflow points to create the tag my self.

Can someone make a tag named 'Avans'?

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314976/is-it-acceptable-if-a-user-introduces-a-new-tag-that-is-highly-specific

Comment: [Meta tags aren't helpful](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/)

Comment: Side note, since you're new to Meta: please note that Meta voting on feature requests indicates agreement or disagreement (so please don't take the downvotes personally).

Comment: Since you're new to Meta, I'd like to (pre-emptively) point out that downvotes here are also used to express disagreement. They won't cost you points. Most new users to Meta find their first posts unpopular, so know that you're not alone. If you stick around for a while, you'll develop a gut feeling for what works here.

Comment: [Here's a helpful post for students posting about homework problems, by the way](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Comment: Aside from your suggestion being an incorrect usage of tags, do note that encouraging students to ask infantile questions in a saturated tag such as `C#` will likely result in poor reception from the community.

Comment: @S.L.Barth that's the truth - re the downvotes. If it's any consolation I have meta posts with >100 downvotes.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

That's not how tags are supposed to work.

Tags are supposed to categorize questions by subject, not by origin. It shouldn't matter that a question originated from your students, or from students from another university, or even another place entirely.

So, this tag will not be created.

You could ask your students to inform you of their accounts, and monitor these yourself. But, please let your students understand what kind of questions are accepted here. Everybody will have a better experience if they understand that the site is for people who tried to solve their own problems first.

Comment: Hmmm that makes sense. I was just looking for a convenient way to monitor my students. I will try to find a different way to achieve my goal!

Comment: @Linksonder, I haven't used it personally so I'm not positive whether this is the case, but perhaps this may be a good use case for the "Stack Overflow Teams" concept that's being so heavily promoted these days.

Comment: @SamHanley: The problem there is that only team members can see / answer the questions. I believe the OP wants the normal userbase to be able to answer these questions.

Comment: @Cerbrus fair - but to the point about teaching students about SO's norms, that may or may not actually be a good idea, depending on the degree to which they're prepared to be a part of the normal userbase as a part of this course.

Comment: Well, i want both. I want students to feel more comfortable asking questions via Stack overflow AND i want to be able to monitor these questions. It's sort of teaching them a best practice.

Comment: @Cerbrus Since most beginner questions are already asked on SO, a Team for the students helping each other would be better. OTOH they wouldn't learn SO's culture that way.

Comment: @S.L.Barth: That's exactly my point. Teams would be both a good and bad choice... That aside, it's [not free of charge](https://stackoverflow.com/pricing)

Comment: @linksonder the best you could do, for your students' experience, is to be the first reviewer of their question, and make sure it is up to par with our quality standard. this way you make sure your student get a good reception, while being sure they don't fish for answers too much. After that, it becomes very easy to monitor, as you have given the go to each question.